# pymongo update an array of subdocuments with values in a list

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have documents in a collection of the format:

```
{'_id': 1, 'customers': [
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
    ]
}
{'_id': 2, 'customers': [
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
    ]
}
{'_id': 3, 'customers': [
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': subval2, 'subkey3': subval3}}},
    ]
}
```

unfortunately I can't give an example document as it is confidential. but the format looks identical.

Now, I process the data like:

```
data = list(pymongo.MongoClient()['db']['collection'].find({}))

processed = []
for item in data:
    item['subkey']['subkey1'] = modify_function(item)
```

processed would now look like:

```
[
    {'_id': 1, 'customers': [
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': new_subval2, 'subkey3': new_subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': new_subval2, 'subkey3': new_subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': new_subval2, 'subkey3': new_subval3}}},
        {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'subkey': {'subkey1': {'subkey2': new_subval2, 'subkey3': new_subval3}}}]},
    {'_id': 2, ....},
    {'_id': 3, ....}
]
```

Question is how do I update just the mongodoc's ['subkey']['subkey1'] with values in the array. all example i've seen so far are setting array with a constant value but here all the sub_vals are different for each subdocument inside the customers array.

I'm trying to achieve:

`bulk_ops = [pymongo.UpdateOne({'_id': doc['_id']}, {'$set': "do update of customers.$.subkey with items in the processed list"} for doc in processed)`

what I'm doing currently: `bulksops = [ReplaceOne({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc) for doc in processed]`

why is this an issue: as you might know when I replace the whole document, the whole document gets encoded from python data types into bson type by pymongo prior to mongodb operation and my document has more such arrays like `customers` and can be arbitrarily large (upto the 16mb limit). that takes a huge performance hit. I've profiled the code and it spends most of the time in _cbson.encode_all() method. I assume if the update document is small, it will be done faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the all positional operator [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#---) to refer to all elements in an array.

For this instance that might look like:

```
{$set: {
    "customers.$[].subkey.subkey1.subkey2": "new_subval2",
    "customers.$[].subkey.subkey1.subkey3": "new_subval3"
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VCEfwtRkEuW)